# Microsoft mocks and mocking out SqlConnection for integration testing

Tags: .net, web-services, testing, integration-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have various web services which talk to each other, sometimes making database calls and some which talk to a message queue, but I'd like to be able to test the services interacting with one another without actually making calls to the database.

Is there a way that I can carry out integration tests without actually hitting the outer extremities of the system i.e. databases and message queues.

Our web services and database are not written with DI or testability in mind so creating fake implementations into services is not really an option. I've seen the Microsoft Mocks library which creates fake versions of an assembly and looks promising.

Is there a way of achieving this using Microsoft fakes?  Can we somehow get the service to make calls to a fake SqlConnection and mock the database calls?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no way to use dependency injection you can try to mock certian components of your DB layer

I suggest take a look to repository pattern

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-2cplusdoneplusright

And try to separate and to abstract all DB model, so after you can mock all this classes using some mocks framework like RhinoMocks

Comment: Can we not do something without actually performing too much surgery on our existing DB layer? I was thinking of Microsoft fakes and some method to switch to the fake assembly.

Comment: If you are using a separated classes for your DB layer you need to instance this classes in some place. You always can use this classes as a property and try to mock it using 'mock by property'

Take a look:
http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Properties.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1